# C#, selecting certain parts from string

Tags: c#, string, select, double, stringreader

In my example I have a string: `"POINT (6.5976512883340064 53.011505757047068)"`

What I would like is to extract the two doubles from that string and place them in separate strings.

I could use a `StringReader`, however the doubles are not fixed in length (aka the length may vary) so I can't state after which position to start selecting.

What I would like is to state that the first selection be made after the "("  and before the whitespace, and the second selection be made after the white space and before the ")". The rest of the string can be ignored.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll get a better response and less downvotes if you show us (code) what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: you can use regex or locate the 1rst "(" & the next space and than use String.Substring..

Comment: Anything you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var point = "POINT (6.5976512883340064 53.011505757047068)";

var indexOfFirstBrace = point.IndexOf('(') + 1;
var indexOfLastBrace = point.IndexOf(')');
var coordinates = point.Substring(indexOfFirstBrace, indexOfLastBrace - indexOfFirstBrace).Split(' ');

var xCoordinate = coordinates[0];
var yCoordinate = coordinates[1];
```

Comment: Tried this and it's exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
var str = "POINT (6.5976512883340064 53.011505757047068)";
var nums = Regex.Replace(a, @"POINT\s*\(([^)]+)\)", "$1").Split(' ');
var x = nums[0];
var y = nums[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    void GetDoubles() 
    {
        string valuesWithoutBrackets = ExtractStringBetweenBrackets("POINT (6.5976512883340064 53.011505757047068)");
        string[] values = valuesWithoutBrackets.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

        //values[0] = "6.5976512883340064"
        //values[1] = "53.011505757047068"
    }

    string ExtractStringBetweenBrackets(string s)
    {
        // You should check for errors in real-world code, omitted for brevity
        var startTag = "(";
        int startIndex = s.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
        int endIndex = s.IndexOf(")", startIndex);
        return s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }
```